# Gimp interface to change to black

Tags: gimp, interface

I am using GIMP 2.6 on Ubuntu 11.10 and wish to chage GIMP's Interface to black. How do I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by choosing an appropriate GTK+ theme. There are a few in Ubuntu already, and a lot more at e.g. http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=100

Note that some theme creators are more interested in the looks than in usability, so you might encounter problem when trying to use GIMP with these themes.

You can install themes for use in GIMP only without affecting your desktop or other applications, this is described in the GIMP user manual: http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-theme

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an answer to your question on [GIMP.org](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24843).

Try `Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Custom color -> Custom padding`.